# Cross product integral along an elipse

Tags: solution-verification, vector-analysis, contour-integration, parametric, cross-product

If C is the curve $r=(x,y):x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ then find $\oint_C{r\times dr}$ in an anticlockwise direction

I varied $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ over the ellipse to get

$r=(acos(\theta),bsin(\theta),0)$

and $dr/d\theta=(-asin(\theta), bcos(\theta),0)$

So that $\oint_C{r\times dr}=\hat{k}\int_0^{2\pi}ab*d\theta$

So the answer is $2\pi(ab)\hat{k}$

Is this correct? The $2\pi$ seems quite arbitrary....

Comment: Does $\pi$ in the area of the circle look arbitrary?

Comment: @IvanNeretin No. So does that mean it's the correct answer? I've never seen an integral of a constant from 0 to $2\pi$ so that's why it was confusing.

Comment: Looks correct to me. That's twice the area of the ellipse, just as it should be.